# Four table data based on LINQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, webforms

I have four Tables

Question Table

| Id | QuestionCode | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 3 |
| 2 | 102 | 3 |
| 3 | 103 | 3 |
| 4 | 104 | 3 |
| 5 | 105 | 3 |

Exam Table

| Id | Exam Name | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Main Exam | 3 |

User Table

| Id | UserId | ExamId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 |

Answer Table

| Id | UserId | ExamId | Questioncode | UserAnswer | RightAnswer | Attempted | RemainingQuestionTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 1 | 101 | A | A | true | 56 |

here I am fetching data from Question table where
if student question is not in the answer table then from the particular exam may fetch next questions.
My query is

```cs
var QuestionList = 
  (from q in db.Question
  from e in db.Exam
  where q.GroupId == e.GroupId 
  from u in db.User
  where e.Id == u.ExamId
  where !db.Answer.Any(x => x.UserId == u.UserId && x.ExamId == e.Id && x.QuestionCode == q.QuestionCode)
  select new
  {
      q
  }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am not getting desired result. So please help.

Comment: Show your classes. LINQ Query is built from classes.

Comment: Your query seems very complicated. I will try to take a look and work on a solution, but the premise is: 1) get a list of all questions for this particular exam and then 2) find questions this user has not attempted yet.

Comment: I use your code and get the question whitch Id is 2, What's your desired result? Can you be more specific about your needs?